# How to get Navbar dropdown option to work without JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, materialize

I am currently trying to create a navbar with a dropdown item in my App.vue file. I read that you can do it without JQuery, so I was hoping someone could assist me with that. I'm getting a bit lost once I get to the point of creating javascript for it.

This is for a front end only website.

```html
   <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    </ul>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
          <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
          <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
          <li>
            <a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">
              Dropdown
              <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Expected result: Navbar with functional dropdown item.
Actual result: Dropdown is currently disabled because I have not implemented any JQuery or JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I think your HTML could firstly do with a little work. Something like this would be more semantically correct:

```
    <nav>
        <a href="/" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
          <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-button">
              Dropdown
              <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
              <ul class="dropdown-content hide">
                <li><a href="/one">one</a></li>
                <li><a href="/two">two</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="/three">three</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Note the `hide` CSS class on the dropdown-content ul.

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Then using your your JS:

```
const trigger = document.querySelector('.dropdown-button');
const content = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');

trigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
   if (content.classList.contains('hide')) {
       content.classList.remove('hide'); // Show the content
   } else {
       content.classList.add('hide'); // Hide the content
   }
});
```